# Android Development DropboxUnlinkedException

Tags: java, android, dropbox

I am writing an Android app with upload a file to Dropbox. However, I do not know
why I encounter DropboxUnlinkedException at runtime after reading some articles on StackOverflow. Can anyone tell me what problem it is?
Actually, I am new to JAVA and Android. Hope that you can explain the problem as well
as the solutions in details. Thanks a lot! :D
(Remarks: I have checked that I can call the uploadFile method. But there is no any response get. I am confused.)

```
public class ConnectToDropBox extends Activity {
    final static private String APP_KEY = "16u74380lodkknv";
    final static private String APP_SECRET = "westpz8i6mqn15g";
    final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.DROPBOX;

    // In the class declaration section:
    private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // And later in some initialization function:
        AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys,
                ACCESS_TYPE);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
        mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(ConnectToDropBox.this);
        try {
            uploadFile();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Required to complete auth, sets the access token on the
                // session
                mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

                String accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void uploadFile() throws DropboxException, FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("/sdcard/letschat/data/backup.txt.part.1");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Entry response = mDBApi.putFile(
                "/sdcard/letschat/data/backup.txt.part.1", inputStream,
                file.length(), null, null);
        Toast.makeText(ConnectToDropBox.this, "HIHI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

}
```

The LogCat is as follows:

```
03-28 20:27:28.269: W/System.err(8283): com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxUnlinkedException
03-28 20:27:28.273: W/System.err(8283):     at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.assertAuthenticated(DropboxAPI.java:2525)
03-28 20:27:28.273: W/System.err(8283):     at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.putFileRequest(DropboxAPI.java:2177)
03-28 20:27:28.273: W/System.err(8283):     at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.putFileRequest(DropboxAPI.java:1498)
03-28 20:27:28.273: W/System.err(8283):     at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.putFile(DropboxAPI.java:1458)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at com.tolmms.backup.ConnectToDropBox.uploadFile(ConnectToDropBox.java:74)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at com.tolmms.backup.ConnectToDropBox.onCreate(ConnectToDropBox.java:45)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 20:27:28.277: W/System.err(8283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-28 20:27:28.281: W/System.err(8283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 20:27:28.281: W/System.err(8283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 20:27:28.281: W/System.err(8283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-28 20:27:28.281: W/System.err(8283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-28 20:27:28.281: W/System.err(8283):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation kinda sucks, it does not tell you that if you dont use onResume, how to code this. I have called the upload in a service.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(God.TAG, "Initializing Dropbox");
        AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(God.DROPBOX_APP_KEY,
                God.DROPBOX_APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
        mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(this);
        if (mDBApi != null && mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Required to complete auth, sets the access token on the session
                mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();
                UploadDB2DropBox upload2DropBox = new UploadDB2DropBox(this,
                        mDBApi);
                upload2DropBox.execute();

                //String accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.i(God.TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```